# Debug .pyz executable

Tags: python, package, pyz

When I run my `main.py` file from console like `python main.py` everything works just fine. However when I package the app with zippapp it opens up window and apparently shows some error which I am unable to read because it immediately closes.

How to debug/resolve this? Is it possible to somehow stop that so I can see the error?

I have folder in which is *data* folder and *app* folder, in the app folder there is *main.py* and there is *my_function()* which is being run. The zipapp command:

`python -m zipapp Entire_package -m app.main:my_function`

Comment: would be good to log to a file the exceptions you are catching...

Comment: But it does not seem like a code error because it does not even execute first command in the ```my_function()``` - seems more like some import problem or something like that - I do not know how to (or is it even possible?) catch these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lulz.

One just have to run the `.pyz` file from terminal/command line with python like this:

`python my_executable_pyz_file.pyz`

and then you get the error printed straight into the terminal/cmd window and you can read it.